# Python 3 Popen.stdin.write encoding issues

Tags: character-encoding, python-3.x, telnet, subprocess

I am attempting to use Popen to automate a simple telnet session. In python 2.6.5 the following code works:

```
openCmd = subprocess.Popen("telnet 192.168.1.1", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
time.sleep(1)
openCmd.stdin.write("username\r")
time.sleep(1)
openCmd.stdin.write("password\r")
time.sleep(1)
openCmd.stdin.write("some command\r")
openCmd.terminate()
```

In python 3 it complained of a type error, so I figured I just had to add .encode() to the end of each str object (as shown below). Adding the .encode() did fix the type error, and I don't get any exceptions, but the command I am trying to run on the remote machine doesn't get run.

```
openCmd = subprocess.Popen("telnet 192.168.1.1", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
time.sleep(1)
openCmd.stdin.write("username\r".encode())
time.sleep(1)
openCmd.stdin.write("password\r".encode())
time.sleep(1)
openCmd.stdin.write("some command\r".encode())
openCmd.terminate()
```

I also tried .encode("ascii") and .encode("UTF-8"). What am I doing incorrectly? I figure the issue is with the encoding, but I do not know for sure... I am running this program on a machine running Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @agf There is no traceback -- the command I am trying to run against the remote machine simply isn't executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all I needed to do was sleep on this one. It turns out that in Python 2.6.5 every

```
Popen.stdin.write()
```

Had a shorter delay before the buffer was flushed than Python 3 did! Here is the final working program:

```
def writeImmeadiatelyToPopen(openCmd, textToWrite):
    openCmd.write(textToWrite.encode())
    openCmd.flush()

openCmd = Popen("telnet 192.168.1.1", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
time.sleep(1)
writeImmeadiatelyToPopen(openCmd, "username\n")
time.sleep(1)
writeImmeadiatelyToPopen(openCmd, "password\n")
time.sleep(1)
writeImmeadiatelyToPopen(openCmd, "some command\n")
openCmd.terminate()
```

In case anyone wondered, I figured out how it worked by running Popen against 'cat' and carefully watching the output in Python 2.6.5 and Python 3 ^_^ .

Answer (score 0):

Use python.pexpect to automate telnet session on Linux.

Comment: White that may be one way to go, that still does not resolve my issue with Popen not working the way I expect.